# haartraining directory on opencv 3.0 to build mergevec

Tags: opencv

i currently developing object detection which requires creating my own object classifier. i stack on merging samples .vec using mergevec.cpp that i have to build mergevec by my self because it's not available for linux built. to build mergevec requires haartraining directory and library.

my question is, where is haartraining library on opencv 3.0 ? i couldn't find it. i have a narrow time to build another opencv version/downgrade to make it works

sorry for bad grammar, thank you for helping my problem

Answer (score 0):

here is the mergevec that you need, now it is a .py

https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec/blob/master/mergevec.py

if you need a tutorial:

https://github.com/wulfebw/mergevec

but if you are following the tutorial you should still use the mergevec of the first link I sent you, because the mergevec of the tutorial is faulty